# MQTT: Getting disconnected again and again on specific client_id

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am facing issue of disconnect on specific client_id. When i am trying to connect,it will suddenly disconnected and shows me error

```
1450599983: New connection from 192.168.2.245 on port 1883.
1450599983: Client 46144 disconnected.
1450599983: New client connected from 192.168.2.245 as 46144 (c0, k60).
1450599984: Socket error on client 46144, disconnecting.
```

And my conf.d file is

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
cleansession true
```

And sometimes it happens after sending message. Why it is happing,how we can reslove this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have multiple clients connecting with the same clientid. The clientid must be unique per client, if a client with the same id as an existing client then the broker disconnects the older client. If you enable full logging on mosquitto it will tell you when this is happening.